# Best way to conditionally chain scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to extend the functionality of my serverside datatable. I pass some extra filters to my controller / datatable, which I use to filter results. Currently in my model I am testing whether the params are present or not before applying my scopes, but I'm not convinced this is the best way since I will have a lot of if/else scenario's when my list of filters grows. How can I do this the 'rails way'?

```
if params[:store_id].present? && params[:status].present?
  Order.store(params[:store_id]).status(params[:status])
elsif params[:store_id].present? && !params[:status].present?
  Order.store(params[:store_id])
elsif !params[:store_id].present? && params[:status].present?
  Order.status(params[:status])
else
  Order.joins(:store).all
end
```

ANSWER:
Combined the answers into this working code:

```
query = Order.all
query = query.store(params[:store_id]) if params[:store_id].present?
query = query.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
query.includes(:store)
```

Comment: why do u need to use one api endpoint to handle 3 different tasks.. why not use 3 end-points instead?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I am filtering my orders by store / status.

Comment: Ahh OK my bad.. I thought u were doing some operation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since relations are chainable, it's often helpful to "build up" your search query. The exact pattern for doing that varies widely, and I'd caution against over-engineering anything, but using plain-old Ruby objects (POROs) to build up a query is common in most of the large Rails codebases I've worked in. In your case, you could probably get away with just simplifying your logic like so:

```
relation = Order.join(:store)

if params[:store_id]
  relation = relation.store(params[:store_id])
end

if params[:status]
  relation = relation.status(params[:status])
end

@orders = relation.all
```

Rails even provides [ways to "undo" logic that has been chained previously](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#overriding-conditions), in case your needs get particularly complex.

Comment: I believe it does not need to join to stores unless both params are not present, right?

Comment: @HoMan: depends on the use case, but my guess is both those scopes are already joining onto stores. If not, the two branches could specify `.unscope(:joins)`, or use a conditional like your answer does.

Comment: Also, your comment got me thinking why I am using the join. It was not needed after all. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 19):

You could do it like this:

```
query = Order
query = query.store(params[:store_id]) if params[:store_id].present?
query = query.status(params[:status]) if params[:status].present?
query = Order.joins(:store) if query == Order
```

Alternatively, you could also just restructure the `status` and `store` scopes to include the condition inside:

```
scope :by_status, -> status { where(status: status) if status.present? }
```

Then you can do this instead:

```
query = Order.store(params[:store_id]).by_status(params[:status])
query = Order.joins(:store) unless (params.keys & [:status, :store_id]).present?
```

Answer (score 1):

The top answer above worked for me. Here is an example of its' real-life implementation:

```
      lessons = Lesson.joins(:member, :office, :group)
      if @member.present?
        lessons = lessons.where(member_id: @member)
      end
      if @office.present?
        lessons = lessons.where(office_id: @office)
      end
      if @group.present?
        lessons = lessons.where(group_id: @group)
      end
      @lessons = lessons.all
```